# "Would have to" usage

Tags: tense, verb-usage

From the article ["Delhi launches doorstep delivery of govt. services"](https://epaper.thehindu.com/Home/ShareArticle?OrgId=GGJ4LR48T.1&imageview=0) in *The Hindu* (emphasis mine):

> The applicant **would have to** call 1076 and fix an appointment with a mobile sahayak, who will go to their home and help with filling forms, payment of fees and collection of documents.

This is an excerpt from a reputed newspaper.Can anyone explain me What is the use of "would have to" in this sentence? Can I use "will have to" instead of "would have to"?

Comment: When 'will have to' is changed to indirect speech with reporting verb in past tense, it becomes 'would have to.'  He said, "I will have to visit them."  He said that he would have to visit them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Will have to" is acceptable here. The use of "will" means that something is certain. "Would have to" can imply a hypothetical situation or that there is only a chance you will have to do it. In this case, the applicant doesn't know if he will get the job, so it's a statement of his *possible* future duties.

Answer (score 0):

Tell a story in the past, but something would happen in the future of the past.

For example, Someone tells a story about he and his father of ten years ago.

> That night, we played happily. But then he told me that he **would have**
>   **to** go in the next morning.

[What is the difference between 'you have to say that' and 'you would have to say that'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/87938/what-is-the-difference-between-you-have-to-say-that-and-you-would-have-to-say)